# TextBox CaretIndex wrong position when pressed key down

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have two `TextBox` with multiline:

FirstTextBox.Text =

```
123456789 abcd
123456789
123456789 abcd
```

SecondTextBox.Text =

```
123456789 abcd
123456789 abcd
123456789 abcd
```

I have `PreviewKeyDown` code for `FirstTextBox`:

```
private void FirstTextBox_PreviewKeyDown (object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Tab)
    {
       newPos = int (...) // Calculate caret position in line
               
       SecondTextBox.Focus ();
       SecondTextBox.CaretIndex = newPos;
       e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Tab works, change `TextBox` is ok, but when press key down in second `TextBox`, caret go to start line.

When pressed keys left or right, `TextBox` "remembers position" and next time caret after change `TextBox` and change to line key pressed down, the caret position it is old caret sets to pressed keys left or right

My question:
How to set "remember position" in `SecondTextBox` to "remember position" in `FirstTextBox`.

I think "remember position" is value in pixel, because when in `TextBox.Text`

```
 wwwwwwwwwwww
 .....................
```

pressed key down or up, caret is the same place (not the same character index in line).